# When is non-normality severe enough to warrant using different tests?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, nonparametric, assumptions, f-test

I've been doing quite a bit of reading on the topic of non-normality, and how it pertains to the F-test. My understanding is that non-normality tests aren't very useful, as outlined in the arguments in this [Cross Validated Thread.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/67220)

However, the following question still stands: if the F-test isn't robust against non-normal data, what should a practitioner do? Upon researching this concern, I've found many resources (for example, this [GraphPad guide](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/statistics/index.htm?stat_qa_normality_tests.htm) that essentially advise the practitioner to keep using the standard tests (i.e., T-test, ANOVA, etc.) if the data is "only approximately Gaussian." OK, but at what point do we step away from, say, the F-test, and use a non-parametric test? When is the non-normality too much?

Comment: Are you asking about normal distributions of the variables themselves, or of the residuals after fitting a model? If you have a particular experimental design in mind then perhaps a more specific answer can be supplied; too often the answer to a general question is: "It depends."

Comment: @EdM- sorry for not mentioning it sooner; the variables themselves.

Comment: The amount of non-normality that can destroy the properties of parametric tests is surprisingly small in some settings.  But which $F$ test are you referring to?  If a test for equality of variances you might also entertain the use of more robust measures of dispersion such as Gini's mean difference.

Comment: @FrankHarrell yes, I am referring to the F-test that compares variances.

Comment: See if bootstrapping the difference in two Gini mean differences is a good idea.